# Add dynamic properties to a dynamic type?

Tags: asp.net, .net, generics, binding, anonymous

Long story short I have to populate a grid with dynamic data (including dynamic columns).  Which is possible when binding the radgrid (telerik tool) to a list of anonymous types.  But I need to add properties to the anonymous object from items read from the database.

```
Dim grdds2 = (From grd As PeerReviewReportByCategoryItems In GetPRReportByCategory(dpkStartDate.SelectedDate, dpkEndDate.SelectedDate, "")
             Select New With {
                .CategoryName = grd.CategoryName,
                .Total = grd.TotalCount,
                .CategoryID = grd.CategoryID,
                .Test = grd.RadiologistCountsString}
                 )

    RadGrid1.DataSource = grdds2
```

For example here I create an anonymous type and bind it to the grid, works perfectly.

But now I need to add properties to the anonymous type with names/values that are read from the database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating an anonymous type, create an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) (assuming you're using .NET 4). That's designed *specifically* for "I want to set a bunch of properties dynamically".

When you know the property name up-front, just use it like any other dynamic type. When you want to access them via variable values (e.g. read from the database) just cast it to `IDictionary(Of Object, Of Object)` and you can set/get values that way.

EDIT: As noted in comments, whether this is bound properly (and automatically) to the grid will depend on whether RadGrid supports dynamic typing. There are ways for it to find out the dynamically-supplied properties, but whether it *does* or not is a different matter.

Comment: I don't think this will work with a control that dynamically creates its columns based on the properties of the bound type, except it was specifically designed for that. As I understand the ExpandoObject, reflection wouldn't return those dynamic properties and thus anything relying on reflection would fail.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: If it's not aware of dynamic typing, that's probably right. I don't know whether the radgrid is or not. Will edit...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it looks like Daniel is right.  Although, now I'm thinking about altering my approach and seeing if I can bind it to an xml object.

Comment: @Javier: What happens if you bind a `Dictionary`?

Comment: It only allows binding of type iList...etc.  Not iDictionary.  I've tried binding a list of keyvaluepairs but no luck

Comment: Yes, I may go that route if the xmldatasource doesn't work. I was avoiding that because of all the extra coding.

Comment: Just to follow up. XML worked perfectly, but I had to convert the xml string to a datatable since the radgrid only allows binding to xml files and not strings.